# MongoDB connection is not connecting to client in localhost

Tags: mongodb, connection, localhost, mean-stack

Setting up a MEAN stack project I'm trying to connect mongodb connection but it is failing. Below is my code. Let me know if any changes required here. Thank you

In my connect.ts file

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

export class MongoUtility {

static readonly collectionNames = {
  stockList: 'StockList'
};

private _mongoClient: MongoClient;
private _tradeTrackDb;
private _connectionStatus: ConnectionStatus;

constructor() {
  this._mongoClient = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017');
  this._init();
}

private _init() {
  this._connectDb();
}

private _connectDb() {
  this._connectionStatus = ConnectionStatus.Connecting;
  this._mongoClient.connect()
    .then(client => {
      const db = client.db().collection('TradeTrack');
      this._tradeTrackDb = db;
      this._tradeTrackDb.on('close', () => {
        this._connectionStatus = ConnectionStatus.Reconnecting;
        console.log('Lost connection to TradeTrackDB. Attempting to reconnect...');
      });
      this._tradeTrackDb.on('reconnect', () => {
        this._connectionStatus = ConnectionStatus.Connected;
        console.log('Recovered connection to TradeTrackDB.');
      })
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.warn('Initial connection attempt to TradeTrackDB failed. Attempting reconnect in 5   seconds.', JSON.stringify(error));
      setTimeout(this._connectDb.bind(this), 5000);
    })
    }
}

enum ConnectionStatus {
  Connecting,
  Connected,
  Reconnecting
```

}

Its coming to catch of `connectDb` method everytime.

Error

```
Initial connection attempt to TradeTrackDB failed. Attempting reconnect   in 5 seconds. {"reason":{"type":"Unknown","servers":{},"stale":false,"compatible":true,"heartbeatFrequencyMS":10000,"localThresholdMS":15,"setName":null,"maxElectionId":null,"maxSetVersion":null,"commonWireVersion":0,"logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes":null}}
```

Comment: What is the error message? Did you start the MongoDB?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit. Yes. Its go to catch and throws the above error(updated my question)